# How To Give Input In Python Selenium In WordPress

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to select one of this category in my WordPress website through input how I can do that please help thanks in advance

**16 gb ram games**

```
category16gbgames = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="in-category-11"]')
category16gbgames.click()
```

**256 mb ram games**

```
category256mbgames = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="in-category-9"]')
category256mbgames.click()
```

**512 mb ram games**

```
category512mbgames = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="in-category-7"]')
category512mbgames.click()
```

**1 gb ram games**

```
category1gbgames = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="in-category-17"]')
category1gbgames.click()
```

**8 gb ram games**

```
category8gbgames = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="in-category-10"]')
category8gbgames.click()
```

**4 Gb Ram Games**

```
category4gbgames = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="in-category-15"]')
category4gbgames.click()
```

**2 Gb Ram Games**

```
category2gbgames = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="in-category-16"]')
category2gbgames.click()
```

**Action Games**

```
actiongames = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="in-category-12"]')
actiongames.click()
```

Please help how to select one category through input in python selenium

Comment: Can you provide resource, so we are able to help you?

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use `f-string` to take the user input for the categories.

```py
game_category = input("choose the category: ") # in-category-9, in-category-11

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="{game_category}"]').click()
```

## or

```py
game_category = input("choose the category: ") # 9, 11, ........

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="in-category-{game_category}"]').click()
```

Comment: I'll go with the first approach. In the second you may need contains.

Comment: it is not working sir unable to locate element

Comment: well, I would be able to help you better if you could provide more details.